# Take input via user in order to execute a last and cut command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cut, tr

I want to prompt a user to cut from a 'last' command along with what columns to cut. I also want to use 'tr' to fix all the difference in white spaces. This is the code I have:

```
echo -n "What rows and columns would you like to cut: "
read num_int
read num_row
read num_list
last $num_int
cut -f $num_row
tr -d $num_list
```

When I run it from the command line I get the prompt, so I hit enter then put in a number to cut. I then hit enter again and I get a list of info that prints to screen but doesn't break out of the executed script. Is there a better way to set this script up? Here's some sample data of what it echo's out to the screen:

```
slater   pts/2        78.189.121.247   Sat Sep  1 23:21 - 23:27  (00:05)    
slater   pts/3        77.189.121.247   Sat Sep  1 23:09 - 23:21  (00:12)    
slater   pts/2        76.189.121.247   Sat Sep  1 22:59 - 23:09  (00:10)    
slater   pts/2        74.189.121.247   Sat Sep  1 22:51 - 22:56  (00:05)    
pint     pts/2        74.189.121.247   Sat Sep  1 22:49 - 22:51  (00:01)    
terry    pts/2        74-119-247-134.r Sat Sep  1 19:08 - 19:09  (00:00)
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is doing this fits your needs ?

```
read -p "What row and column integers would you like to cut >>> " col row
 last | awk -v col=$col -v row=$row 'NR==row{print $col}'
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for. I should have used awk in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do here. But I'm pretty sure you want to pipe those commands to each other so they operate on each other's output:

```
last | cut -f $num_row | tr -d $num_list
```

`last $num_int` probably doesn't do what you want. `last` expects usernames as arguments. To get the last `$num_int` lines of output, try `tail` (or maybe `head`):

```
last | tail -n $num_int | cut -f $num_row | tr -d $num_list
```

The `tr` command I'm particularly confused about. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: I just want to get rid of the non-printing characters with 'tr.'